# How to replicate the window transparency effect found in the new DropBox UWP app

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

Apparently the effect is a feature introduced in the Creator's Update. Has anyone figured out the exact APIs used to pull this off? Even better would be some example code to at least help get me started.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :]

Comment: Without screenshots I can only assume that you're talking about Windows.UI.Composition.Compositor.CreateHostBackdropBrush() API. It will create a brush that you can apply to Visual

Answer (score 5):

You should target Windows Creators Update for it to work

```
 using Windows.UI.Xaml.Hosting;

 //'this' is MainPage, but can be any UIElement
 var visual = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(this);
 var brush = visual.Compositor.CreateHostBackdropBrush();
 var sprite = visual.Compositor.CreateSpriteVisual();
 sprite.Brush = brush;
 //Set to the size of the area, update on SizeChanged
 sprite.Size = new System.Numerics.Vector2(1000, 1000); 
 ElementCompositionPreview.SetElementChildVisual(this, sprite);
```

Comment: I was able to use this on the Main page, however the content on the main page (Pivot) is now hidden.

Any way to fix that?

Comment: @Shubhan, at last line instead of `this` use some element on your page that you use as background.

Comment: @x2 Agreed that we can use any element as the background, in my case I was using the main page itself. It's prefered to use a Grid in most scenarios