# Microsoft Neon Style Navigation

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, user-interface

With the latest Update from Groove Music Microsoft introduced a new styling theme called "Neon". As far as I know MS is planning to Update at least some more of their UWP-Apps, so that they also make use of this new Design Style, which has semi-transparent navigation bars.

Here is an example of how it looks like:[image]

So I was wondering "Is it possible to create an Application that looks similar?"

As far as I can tell, MS should be using some mix of transparency and Gaussian-Blur-Effects. That's not really the problem, the interesting part starts by making the Window transparent itself, while keeping the Window-Control-Buttons.

When I search for tutorials and How-To's to make an WPF-Application transparent they all set two properties on the window-object.

```
AllowTranparency="True"
```

and

```
WindowStyle="None"
```

With the latter one removing the Title Bar.

So my question is, is there a "new" way of adding opacity to your window, without setting the WindowStyle to None?
And if yes, how?

Otherwise, is it more likely that MS used DWM to give the illusion of transparency, while actually projecting the overlapped part of the window behind the navigation?

I hope that my question is not to widespread about the topic and clearly asked. If not, I'm going to rewrite it and try to clear things up.

Thanks in advance for any answers and hints.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replicate the window transparency effect found in the new DropBox UWP app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43566178/how-to-replicate-the-window-transparency-effect-found-in-the-new-dropbox-uwp-app)